How to scroll ag-grid react table horizontally by grabbing and dragging on the table body
I am trying to have a table that will be scrollable horizontally by grabbing with the mouse cursor and dragging left of right.
This is the current state of the ag-grid component
<div className="py-5" style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <AgGridReact
        rowData={rowData}
        columnDefs={colDefs}
        defaultColDef={{
          sortable: false,
          resizable: false,
          cellStyle: {
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            fontSize: '12px',
          },
          // minWidth: 100,
        }}
        rowClass={'hover:bg-gray-50'}
        rowHeight={60}
        domLayout="autoHeight"
        autoSizeStrategy={{type: 'fitCellContents', }}
        suppressColumnVirtualisation={true}
        suppressCellFocus={true}
        enableCellTextSelection={true}
        suppressRowHoverHighlight={true}
      />
    </div>

